# Show hidden div with bookmarks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I hide all of the answer divs on the page, but I want to show a div if the a user has clicked a bookmarked link to it.

Here's the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
        $(".faq_answer").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        $(".faq_question").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".faq_answer").slideToggle("normal");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The resulting HTML for the section is

```
<li>
  <div class="faq_question">
     <a href="#url-blah" name="url-blah">Question</a>
  </div>
  <div class="faq_answer">
    <p>Text to show</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

**EDIT**

The question was how do I do it...Figured it out though after the answers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.hash` will give you the value "#" in your URL. You can use that to build a selector.

```
// if visiting /index.php#item1
$(window.location.hash).show(); // $('#item1').show();
```

Comment: Did this and then added the window.location.hash value to the id of the answer link.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the `#url-blah` in the URL in javascript and display the corresponding section?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you would need to add a class to the div that hides it and shows it based on the click function

I dont really see a question here though

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you are going to most likely need to change your document structure a bit, as you cannot reference any of the specific "faq_answer" items individually.

Typically what I would do here is use a specific ID for each of the answers, then you can use javascript with a show action to be able to toggle visibility.

For an example of my HTML and jQuery code, you can view [this page](http://www.iowacomputergurus.com/free-products/dotnetnuke-modules/dnn-expandable-text-html.aspx), look at the version history section.